# How to move a project into a new organization without repos?

Tags: azure-devops

I have to move a project into a new organization, but they never enabled repos, so this isn't an option.

[image: As you can see in this image, repos isn't there]

All Microsoft solutions that I can see rely on repos. Is there any other way to do this ?

Old posts here mention that Microsoft might be working on it. Have they ?

Edit: Basically, I have these two organizations

[image]

DTS-STN being an old organization, and SRE-IFS being a new one.
I have to more everything DTS-STN contains into SRE-IFS

If this helps, here is an idea of what DTS-STN contains

[image]

How can I move all the tasks and documents in one-go ?